# reduce a list in scala by value

Tags: scala, reduce

How can I reduce a list like below concisely

```
Seq[Temp] = List(Temp(a,1), Temp(a,2), Temp(b,1))
```

to

```
List(Temp(a,2), Temp(b,1))
```

Only keep Temp objects with unique first param and max of second param.

My solution is with lot of groupBys and reduces which is giving a lengthy answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**you have to**

- `groupBy`
- `sortBy` values in ASC order
- get the `last` one which is the largest

Example,

```
scala> final case class Temp (a: String, value: Int)
defined class Temp

scala> val data : Seq[Temp] = List(Temp("a",1), Temp("a",2), Temp("b",1))
data: Seq[Temp] = List(Temp(a,1), Temp(a,2), Temp(b,1))

scala> data.groupBy(_.a).map { case (k, group) => group.sortBy(_.value).last }
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Temp] = List(Temp(b,1), Temp(a,2))
```

or instead of `sortBy(fn).last` you can `maxBy(fn)`

```
scala> data.groupBy(_.a).map { case (k, group) => group.maxBy(_.value) }
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Temp] = List(Temp(b,1), Temp(a,2))
```

Comment: You can change sortBy(_.value).last to maxBy(_.value)

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a `Map` with `groupBy`, compute the `max` in `mapValues` and convert it back to the `Temp` classes as in the following example:

```
case class Temp(id: String, value: Int)

List(Temp("a", 1), Temp("a", 2), Temp("b", 1)).
  groupBy(_.id).mapValues( _.map(_.value).max ).
  map{ case (k, v) => Temp(k, v) }
// res1: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Temp] = List(Temp(b,1), Temp(a,2))
```

Worth noting that the solution using `maxBy` in the other answer is more efficient as it minimizes necessary transformations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `foldLeft`:

```
data.foldLeft(Map[String, Int]().withDefaultValue(0))((map, tmp) => {
    map.updated(tmp.id, max(map(tmp.id), tmp.value))
  }).map{case (i,v) => Temp(i, v)}
```

This is essentially combining the logic of `groupBy` with the `max` operation in a single pass.

**Note** This may be less efficient because `groupBy` uses a `mutable.Map` internally which avoids constantly re-creating a new map. If you care about performance and are prepared to use mutable data, this is another option:

```
val tmpMap = mutable.Map[String, Int]().withDefaultValue(0)

data.foreach(tmp => tmpMap(tmp.id) = max(tmp.value, tmpMap(tmp.id)))

tmpMap.map{case (i,v) => Temp(i, v)}.toList
```

Use a `ListMap` if you need to retain the data order, or sort at the end if you need a particular ordering.